# Apply on every input

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a `FlinkKafkaConsumer011` subscribed to a topic. I wish to process (`apply`) on every kafka consumer message, hence custom `FooTrigger` which returns `TriggerResult.FIRE` on every element.

Following code works, I am just confused by the `timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(1))`. It looks like I am doing something wrong.

```
// set up streaming execution environment
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

// create a Kafka consumer
FlinkKafkaConsumer011<Foo> consumer =  new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(
    "topic",
    new Foo.FooSchema(),
    props);   // Properties object

// create Kafka consumer data source
DataStream<FooTuple> trades = env.addSource(consumer)
    .timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(1))
    .trigger(new FooTrigger())
    .evictor(new FooEvictor())
    .apply(new CreateFoos());
```

Comment: If you want to apply some process to each Kafka message, just use a `map` function. There is no need to aggregate data using `window` functions. Just use: `env.addSource(consumer).map()`

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try! It makes a lot more sense then the provided solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to apply a function to every event in a stream, a [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html) would be a more natural way to do this in Flink. Or in simpler cases, you can use a map or flatmap, or their rich variants, i.e., a RichMapFunction or RichFlatMapFunction -- it all depends on what you are trying to do.

With a map or flatmap you can perform a stateless one-to-one or one-to-many transformation, their rich variants can use keyed state, and a ProcessFunction can use state and timers (provided the stream has been keyed).

timeWindowAll is for cases where the stream is not partitioned by a key, and you want to do non-parallel processing in batches defined by a time duration (for keyed, parallel windowing, use timeWindow instead). If all you want to do is to process data as it arrives, then windowing adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Great, thank you. The same question still remains, why does one need `timeWindowAll()` etc if all I wish to do is process the data when it arrives? If I read the provided example, It says do something every minute with a custom trigger. It's a bit contraversial, don't you think?

Comment: What example are you referring to?

Comment: Code in the question.

Comment: What I mean is, where did this code come from? If a misleading/confusing example is being distributed with Flink, I'd like to fix it.

Comment: Oh, It's just an example prototype code I am working with.